# Is there a way to download over LAN using DownloadManager in android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, lan, android-download-manager

I'm developing an app that needs to play a list of videos on an android TV. At first, I play the video by streaming it while also starting a download for the video. When a specific video is already downloaded and it is the one that needs to be played, I use that downloaded video file and play it. On devices (like the tablet that I used for testing) that is using a `WIFI` connection, the videos are being downloaded. But the TV where I need to run my app is using a LAN connection. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Currently, this is how I start my downloads.

```
public void startDownload(VideoAd videoAd) {
    String videoUrl = videoAd.getUrl();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);

    Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            .mkdirs();

    lastDownload = dlMgr.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                        .setTitle("Downloading video ad")
                        .setDescription("Downloading "+getVideoNameFromLink(videoUrl))
                        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, getVideoNameFromLink(videoUrl)));


    videoAd.setDownloadId(lastDownload);
}
```

It works. But the problem is it doesn't work on LAN connections.

This is what I currently use in my app.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    networkArr = connMgr.getAllNetworks();

    Log.d(TAG, "networkArr len: "+networkArr.length);
    for(Network n : networkArr){
        lblNetworks.setText(n.toString()+"\n");
    }
}else{
    // Use getAllNetworkInfo()
    NetworkInfo[] networkInfArr = connMgr.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for(NetworkInfo ni : networkInfArr){
        lblNetworks.setText(ni.toString()+"\n");
    }
}
```

My tablet is running Lollipop and the number I'm getting is `103`. I can't try it on the TV because it's on a different building.

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to get the network you want and bind your process to this network via connectivity manager. See [bindProcessToNetwork](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)). You can get the network needed via [getAllNetworks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworks())() iterate over them and check if the network info matches the network info you would like.

Comment: Hi. I tried your solution but what I only get is a number with 3 digits. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you elaborate? when do you get 3 digits? Maybe post the code?

Answer (score 1):

For TV, 'NETWORK_MOBILE' wont work. I would suggest to remove it and try with below mentioned code:-

```
lastDownload = dlMgr.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                    .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
                    .setTitle("Downloading video ad")
                    .setDescription("Downloading "+getVideoNameFromLink(videoUrl))
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, getVideoNameFromLink(videoUrl)));
```

If this code works for TV, you need to apply a check(if it is TV) and handle code accordingly.

Comment: Well, I just used what I found before. Thanks. And our android TV are not really a real android TV but I have a way to do the checking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck with this problem. but I solved this but I code in kotlin.
You can try this.

```html
 // request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI) // comment this and use code below
    request.setAllowedOverMetered(false) <---
```

I can download it with Ethernet.

PS. My English is not good but I want to help you.

this is my code in kotlin.

```html
private fun startDownloading(path: String, urlFile: String, name: String, type: String) {
        // handle permission
        try {
            e(subTag,"Download ...")
            val url = urlFile
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            //request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            request.setAllowedOverMetered(false)
//        request.setTitle("Download")
//        request.setDescription("The file is downloading...")
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
//        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(File("$path/$name.$type")))
            val manager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            downloadId =  manager.enqueue(request)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e(subTag,"ERROR startDownloading >> $e")
        }
    }
```